# What if you put a manifest="cache.manfest" in a .cfm page?

Tags: coldfusion

We're developing a tablet app, and my coworker had a rogue thought:

> What if you put a manifest attribute on the html tag of a ColdFusion page?  Would it
>   still work if the user couldn't get to the server?

I think it's lunacy, but I wanted to hear what you guys had to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client side is not aware of how is generated the page. He didn't even know if the page is generated. So, the page is cached like another page.

If you are not connected, the could handle this case with some javascript and alert the user you can't communicate with the server.
You could simply disable the application or work with localStorage etc...